# React/Material-Table | Why is onFilterChanged returning rows where the filtered value is null?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date, filtering, material-table

First of all, I appriciate it, that you are checking out my question. Thanks for that.

I am working on a table which is realised with "material-table" for React. My problem is that, I need custom filtering. I managed to get it working for all rows except the ones which are dates. Although the filter function is doing it's job and returns the row which matches the filter value, it also returns every row which has a null in the same column. I will provide the code below and will appriciate any help given.

```
{
  title: "def. L-Datum",
  field: "definitiver_Liefertermin",
  type: "date",
  filterComponent: (props) => {
    return (
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        style={{ width: 140 }}
        error="none"
        fullWidth
        clearable
        autoOk
        onChange={(e) =>
          props.onFilterChanged(
            props.columnDef.tableData.id,
            e === null ? null : e._d
          )
        }
        value={
          props.columnDef.tableData.filterValue !== undefined &&
          props.columnDef.tableData.filterValue !== null
            ? props.columnDef.tableData.filterValue
            : null
        }
        format="DD-MM-YYYY"
      />
    );
  },
```

The shown code is doing following:

[image: Initial state of table]

[image: After putting in date which shouldn't match any row]

Upon entering a date, it filters the order array to find matching values in each element. When found, it will be displayed in the table. As I said, it is doing that, however it is also showing every row which has the value **null** in the same column, in the pictures it is the first two rows.